# RadSideDrawer -- Open Drawer not working

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have been attempting to add a side drawer to my component [using the following tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started).

However whenever I tap the button that is supposed to call the openDrawer function it is never reached. I have tried structuring my tap component as tap="{{openDrawer}}" to no avail.

After researching this problem I found a [git issue that says tap does not work when a css class is present](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/14). But this project contains the latest version of NativeScripts so it should not be an issue. Finally if I add

> this.drawer.showDrawer();

inside ngOnInit() it still does not appear. No errors in the console.

Below is my code.

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../search.service';
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'header-bar',
    templateUrl: './header-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header-bar.component.css']
})

export class HeaderBarComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawer) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //dont think this method is ever executed
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.openDrawer();
     }

     public openDrawer() {
         console.log(this.drawer); //returns undefined
         console.log("Drawer method reached");
         this.drawer.showDrawer();
     }

     public onCloseDrawerTap() {
         this.drawer.closeDrawer();
     }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <AbsoluteLayout tkMainContent dock="top" >
        <Button class="header-bar"></Button>
        <Image src="res://logo" height="77" width="95" class="logo"></Image>
        <Button left="250" text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label text="Close Drawer" color="lightgray" padding="10" style="horizontal-align: center" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a sidedrawer angular template using sidekick. and then compare your code with that.

Comment: I am doing that now

Comment: Super! Let me know how it goes

Comment: so the project created using tns commands uses nativescript-telerik-ui which is deprecated. I cannot find a tns command to create a nativescript-pro-ui side drawer project

Comment: console.log(this.header) returns undefined. Even though it has been add to app.module

Comment: Just uninstall telerik ui plugin and do tns install nativescript-pro-ui and put the correct reference in the xml. Nothing else has changed.

Comment: I tried but I got this error https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/304 . The solution to this is to uninstal telerik and install ui pro!!

Comment: If you read my comment, that is what I said